# Bug on Bluetooth settings in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, system-settings

I know there is a lot of topics around this issue, but now it's strange since Bluetooth seems to /should work. When I do

> sudo service bluetooth status

I get the following result which seems to be working (I put directly the image so one can check the green highlights)

[image: result from sudo service bluetooth status]

But on **settings->bluetooth**

[image]

the result of command  `hcitool dev` is empty, i.e.

```
Devices:
```

and the result of `hcitool scan` is

```
Device is not available: No such device
```

How can I activate the Bluetoth in settings?

Comment: What is the output of `hcitool dev` and `hcitool scan` (add output to question)?

Comment: @N0rbert done it

Comment: So it is not bug. Ubuntu did not find your Bluetooth hardware. Do you have any? Add output of `lsmod | grep blue`, `rfkill list` and `lspci -vvv | grep -A10 -i "bluetooth\|wireless\|network"` to question.

Comment: Also need to edit question to add results from terminal for `lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was checking in the Internet and found a similar issue. I solved thus my problem with a very simple and brute way.

Go to **Ubuntu Software Centre** and search with keyword "Bluetooth". Then install everything :) I know, it's stupid and brute, but it worked for me and never had problems again.

[image]